# mongodb c# driver set _id of bson document

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

When creating a bson document with a custom id like in the following example, the _id is not 123, it will be auto generated

```
var balls = dbContext.Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Balls");
var ballDoc = new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"_id", BsonObjectId.Parse("123")},
                    {"Name", ".."},
                };

 await balls.InsertOneAsync(ballDoc).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When doing that:

```
var balls = dbContext.Database.GetCollection<Balls>("Balls");
var ball = new Ball
                {
                  Id = ...
                };

 await balls.InsertOneAsync(ball).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The id is 123.
Why? And how can I set an _id when using bson docs?

Comment: I just tried your above sample code and it works fine.

Comment: Actually what type is `dbContext`? and is Database just a `IMongoDatabase`?

Comment: yeah sorry 123 is working fine the problem comes ONLY when setting the _id of the bson object to 000000000000000000000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

123 is working fine the problem comes ONLY when setting the _id of the bson object to 000000000000000000000000. Everything else like 000000000000000000000001 works.
But setting the _id of a typed object to 000000000000000000000000 works....
I need to live with it.